# Associate a proggress bar to the execution of a method

Tags: java, javafx, progress-bar

How can i asociate the advance of a progress bar to the execution of a method which I know the execution time ?
This is the code of my controller class

```
@FXML
void elaboraVideo(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

    if(control == false) {

        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Impossibile proseguire");
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setContentText("Nessun video selezionato!");
        alert.show();

    } else {

        long inizio = System.currentTimeMillis();
        videoM.workVideo(absolutePath);
        long fine = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long time=(inizio-fine)/1000;
        load.setProgress(time);

    }

}
```

the method is workVideo and it's located in an other class.

This is the code of workVideo and it works.

```
ConfigGeneralDetector confDetector = new ConfigGeneralDetector();
            confDetector.threshold = 1;
            confDetector.maxFeatures = 300;
            confDetector.radius = 3;

            // Use a KLT tracker
            PointTracker<ImageFloat32> tracker = FactoryPointTracker.klt(new int[]{1,2,4,8},confDetector,3,
                    ImageFloat32.class,ImageFloat32.class);

            // This estimates the 2D image motion
            // An Affine2D_F64 model also works quite well.
            ImageMotion2D<ImageFloat32,Homography2D_F64> motion2D =
                    FactoryMotion2D.createMotion2D(220,3,2,30,0.6,0.5,false,tracker,new Homography2D_F64());

            // wrap it so it output color images while estimating motion from gray
            ImageMotion2D<MultiSpectral<ImageFloat32>,Homography2D_F64> motion2DColor =
                    new MsToGrayMotion2D<ImageFloat32,Homography2D_F64>(motion2D,ImageFloat32.class);

            // This fuses the images together
            StitchingFromMotion2D<MultiSpectral<ImageFloat32>,Homography2D_F64>
                    stitch = FactoryMotion2D.createVideoStitchMS(0.5, motion2DColor, ImageFloat32.class);

            // Load an image sequence
            MediaManager media = DefaultMediaManager.INSTANCE;
            String fileName = UtilIO.pathExample(path);
            SimpleImageSequence<MultiSpectral<ImageFloat32>> video =
                    media.openVideo(fileName, ImageType.ms(3, ImageFloat32.class));

            MultiSpectral<ImageFloat32> frame = video.next();

            // shrink the input image and center it
            Homography2D_F64 shrink = new Homography2D_F64(0.5,0,frame.width/4,0,0.5,frame.height/4,0,0,1);
            shrink = shrink.invert(null);

            // The mosaic will be larger in terms of pixels but the image will be scaled down.
            // To change this into stabilization just make it the same size as the input with no shrink.
            stitch.configure(frame.width,frame.height,shrink);
            // process the first frame
            stitch.process(frame);

            // Create the GUI for displaying the results + input image
            ImageGridPanel gui = new ImageGridPanel(1,2);
            //gui.setImage(0,0,new BufferedImage(frame.width,frame.height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB));
            gui.setImage(0,1,new BufferedImage(frame.width,frame.height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB));
            gui.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(frame.width*2,frame.height*2));
            gui.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

            ShowImages.showWindow(gui,"Example Mosaic", true);

            boolean enlarged = false;

            // process the video sequence one frame at a time
            while( video.hasNext() ) {
                frame = video.next();
                if( !stitch.process(frame) )
                    throw new RuntimeException("You should handle failures");

                // if the current image is close to the image border recenter the mosaic
                StitchingFromMotion2D.Corners corners = stitch.getImageCorners(frame.width,frame.height,null);
                if( nearBorder(corners.p0,stitch) || nearBorder(corners.p1,stitch) ||
                        nearBorder(corners.p2,stitch) || nearBorder(corners.p3,stitch) ) {
                    stitch.setOriginToCurrent();

                    // only enlarge the image once
                    if( !enlarged ) {
                        enlarged = true;
                        // double the image size and shift it over to keep it centered
                        int widthOld = stitch.getStitchedImage().width;
                        int heightOld = stitch.getStitchedImage().height;

                        int widthNew = widthOld*2;
                        int heightNew = heightOld*2;

                        int tranX = (widthNew-widthOld)/2;
                        int tranY = (heightNew-heightOld)/2;

                        Homography2D_F64 newToOldStitch = new Homography2D_F64(1,0,-tranX,0,1,-tranY,0,0,1);

                        stitch.resizeStitchImage(widthNew, heightNew, newToOldStitch);
                        gui.setImage(0, 1, new BufferedImage(widthNew, heightNew, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB));
                    }
                    corners = stitch.getImageCorners(frame.width,frame.height,null);
                }
                // display the mosaic
                ConvertBufferedImage.convertTo(frame,gui.getImage(0, 0),true);
                ConvertBufferedImage.convertTo(stitch.getStitchedImage(), gui.getImage(0, 1),true);

                // draw a red quadrilateral around the current frame in the mosaic
                Graphics2D g2 = gui.getImage(0,1).createGraphics();
                g2.setColor(Color.RED);
                g2.drawLine((int)corners.p0.x,(int)corners.p0.y,(int)corners.p1.x,(int)corners.p1.y);
                g2.drawLine((int)corners.p1.x,(int)corners.p1.y,(int)corners.p2.x,(int)corners.p2.y);
                g2.drawLine((int)corners.p2.x,(int)corners.p2.y,(int)corners.p3.x,(int)corners.p3.y);
                g2.drawLine((int)corners.p3.x,(int)corners.p3.y,(int)corners.p0.x,(int)corners.p0.y);

                gui.repaint();
                // throttle the speed just in case it's on a fast computer
                BoofMiscOps.pause(50);

            }
            ImageIO.write(gui.getImage(0, 1), "jpg", new File("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/provaaa.jpg"));
            Image img = gui.getImage(0, 1);
            return img;
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean here. You don't know the execution time of the method until it's actually finished, so you can't really hope to make the progress bar advance while it executes. Or did I misunderstand what you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to advance the progress bar until the end of the execution method

Comment: Unless you have some way of knowing what proportion of the execution is complete *while it is executing*, there's no possible way you can do that.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you posted the code for `workVideo`.

Comment: in this way the proress bar advances after the execution of the method

Comment: Do you have any way of knowing how many frames the video has before you start processing it?

Comment: I solved thanks to javafx multithreading. Thanks for your help.